# Email being sent out multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have written a javascript code which handles inputs from a contact form. Using Ajax I send the input information to the backend to send out an email.

However, it seems that my code is somehow sending multiple emails out instead of one. The "Email is sent" message is showing a few times.

Could anyone tell me what went wrong?

**JAVASCRIPT CODE:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.individual_contact', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var user_name = $('span#user-name').text();
    var recipient_name = $(this).attr('data-ind');
    console.log('recipient_name='+recipient_name);

    $("div#content").hide('fast');
    $("#section-form").show('fast');
    $("#section-form #recipient").attr('data-contact', recipient_name);
    $("#section-form #recipient").attr('placeholder', 'TO:  '+recipient_name.toUpperCase());
    $("#section-form #name").val('FROM:  '+user_name.toUpperCase());

    $('.submit_icontact').click(function(e) {
        var subject = $('input#subject').val();
        var message = $('textarea#message').val();

        e.preventDefault();
        var form = new FormData();
        form.append('user_email', ajaxobject.user_id);
        form.append('user_name', user_name);
        form.append('recipient_name', recipient_name);
        form.append('subject', subject);
        form.append('message', message);
        form.append('action', 'contact_individual');
        console.log(form);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxobject.ajaxurl,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log('Email is sent');
            },
            error:function(err){
                console.log('err,error')
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: Each time that you click on .individual_contact, it adds another event handler to .submit_icontact, so clicking .individual_contact once means that clicking .submit_icontact sends 1 email, clicking .individual_contact twice means .submit_icontact sends 2 emails, etc.  You should only assign the event handler to .submit_icontact once.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. You were right. @James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change:**

```
$('.submit_icontact').click(function(e) {
```

**To:**

```
$('.submit_icontact').unbind().click(function(e) {
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for ! Thank you so much!

Comment: ApplePie, is there any chance you could mark my answer as the solution/correct answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Each time you click on a `.individual_contact` you add another event listener to `.submit_icontact`.

Move your `.submit_icontact` click event out of your `.individual_contact` click handler

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Moving the .submit_icontact did solve the issue.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer as it explains the root cause of the multiple submits. thank you.